# Chamar Alert Quando Recebo um Valor na Session

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, alert

Olá!

Estou tentando chamar um alert do javascript assim que recebo algum valor em uma Session. Estou usando C# com ASP.NET

Segue meu código com a tentativa de mostrar o alert, mas sem sucesso:

```
@if((string)Session["alertaErro"] != null)
{
    <script>
        function chamalerta() {
            bootbox.alert(@Session["alertaErro"]);
        }

        chamalerta();
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Onde o valor da Session alertaErro é atribuido?

Comment: você pode tentar colocar um $(document).ready(function(){chamalerta();});

Comment: Jean, a Session recebe o valor quando o usuário tenta acessar alguma página que ele não tem permissão. Mas a Session tem valor dentro dela, já fiz os testes, só queria exibir a mensagem como um alert, pq hj estou exibindo a mensagem em uma div

Comment: Bruno, tentei fazer do jeito que você falou mas ele me retorna alguns erros e não passa pelo bloco que chama a função, ele apenas identifica que a Session está nula e não passa pelo script.

Erros: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
          Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at